# Configuring Google App Engine Python runtime on IntelliJ

Tags: python, google-app-engine, intellij-idea

I can't seem to be able to add the Google App Engine Python runtime on IntelliJ. I tried to add an additional Python SDK and configure my project to use that, but I can't find the correct Python runtime to point to.

Note that I'm not interested in using the PyCharm IDE, and want to maintain the polyglot IntelliJ IDE setup.

My setup:

- IntelliJ Ultimate 13.1
- Python plugin
- Google App Engine Plugin
- Google Cloud SDK

Relevant links:

- https://cloud.google.com/sdk/
- http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?id=631
- https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/quickstart/appengine_guide.html

Answer (score 2):

You probably solve this task and find right approach for you.
I'll just add my solution for this task for IntelliJ 2016 and later, probably earlier version too.

At first, I advise you to crate `virtualenv`. And install `gcloud` and Google App Engine itself using cloud toolkit.

Next, open in IDE your project by selecting proper folder.
Go to **File** > **Project structure** (Mac) and in **Project Settings** section > **Project**, in **Project SDK** drop-down choose /or set your newly crated `virtualenv`.

After that, go to **Modules** in the same section, and hit + sign. Choose **New Module** from context menu. Go to Python section, and there mark **Google App Engine (Python)** checkbox. Set your `Application ID` in proper field beneath checkbox list, and choose path to `Google App Engine SDK`. If you set SDK trough `gcloud` toolset, you can get right path by using `gcloud info` command in console by your favour. Path that you are looking for is `Installation Root` and add `/platform/google_appengine` to it.

Congratulations. You are good to go!